# MySQL Conditional LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with a one to many relationship. Place and Promo. A place can have several promos, which apply by day of the week.

Simplifying (most columns are omitted), These are the tables:

Place

```
idnum   nombre
--
42      SUBWAY
55376   ANTOJERIA MAKECH
50112   TORTAS BERNAL LAS ORIGINALES DESDE 1960
55185   LA MARINERA
```

Promo

```
idnum   titulo                  dia     idcliente
135     Pescado Frito 2 x 1     Lunes   55185
136     Pescado Frito 2 x 1     Martes  55185
137     Margaritas 2 x 1        Jueves  55185
138     Tacos 3 x 2             Viernes 55185
139     5 cervezas              Sabado  55185
```

I want to build a Query that gets me all the Place results, and if available, gets me the corresponding Promo. This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT d.nombre, a.dia, a.descripcion FROM directorio as d LEFT JOIN avisos as a ON d.idnum = a.idcliente WHERE palabras LIKE "%Marinera%" LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0) AS t WHERE t.dia = "Sabado" OR t.dia IS NULL;
```

It works just fine when dia matches the query (in this case "Sabado") or when dia is NULL (for when the place has no promos); but **the problem comes when the place does have promos but none of them matches dia**... in that case I would like to still get the record with null values on the promo columns.

Comment: You need a set of all dias which you can use for an outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the response also when the dia != form "Sabado" then you can use a CASE WHEN

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM (
      SELECT d.nombre, case when a.dia = "Sabado"  then a.dia else NULL END, a.descripcion 
      FROM directorio as d 
      LEFT JOIN avisos as a ON d.idnum = a.idcliente 
      WHERE palabras LIKE "%Marinera%" LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0) AS t 
  WHERE t.dia = "Sabado" 
  OR t.dia IS NULL;
```

this with  max(dia) for remove duplicated  row

```
  SELECT 
        idnum
      , nombre
      , MAX(dia) as dia
      , descripcion 
  FROM ( 
        SELECT 
              d.idnum
            , d.nombre
            , case when a.dia = "Domingo" then a.dia else NULL END as dia
            , a.descripcion FROM directorio as d 
      LEFT JOIN avisos as a ON d.idnum = a.idcliente 
      WHERE palabras LIKE "%Marinera%"
      LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0) AS t 
  WHERE t.dia = "Domingo" OR t.dia IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. It gave me duplicate results so I changed this a bit: 
SELECT idnum, nombre, MAX(dia) as dia, descripcion 
  FROM (
      SELECT d.idnum, d.nombre, case when a.dia = "Domingo"  then a.dia else NULL END as dia, a.descripcion 
      FROM directorio as d 
      LEFT JOIN avisos as a ON d.idnum = a.idcliente 
      WHERE palabras LIKE "%Marinera%"LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0) AS t 
  WHERE t.dia = "Domingo" 
  OR t.dia IS NULL

Comment: @Multitut   . well  seems that the use of case  as i suggested is useful  .. thel  can  i think that my answer  lead  you to the correct result ? ..if  is so please mark my answer  as  accepted too.

Comment: Sure just modify it accordingly please.